# Web API ASP.NET publicada no IIS não funciona

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis

Tenho um projecto ASP.NET Web API que integro com o Primavera 10.

Segui os exemplos que estão no [GitHub](https://github.com/PrimaverabssDeveloper/ERP10Integration) e também a parte do [Assembly Resolver](https://developers.primaverabss.com/?s=assembly&cpt=v10&main-term=253&post=4734).

Quando corro o projecto no IIS Express através do Visual Studio, tudo funciona.

Quando publico para o IIS Local e tento aceder, dá-me um erro em todos os métodos que utilizam o PriEngine, ou seja, quando tento interagir com o Primavera.

O erro que me aparece é o seguinte:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
at WebAPI.Engine.PriEngine.CreatContext(String Company, String User, String Password)
```

São necessárias algumas configurações adicionais para publicar o projecto?

Comment: Talvez partilhar o erro possa ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado @JorgeCosta, o problema era nas configurações da pool da aplicação

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Após uma pesquisa mais exaustiva encontrei a solução para o meu problema no seguinte [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/377633/17084)

É necessário alterar alguns valores default na Aplication Pool para permitir o correcto funcionamento da aplicação:

- Ativar Aplicações de 32 Bits: **True**
- Identidade: **LocalSystem**